# Can iptables redirect specifc domain's request to a dedicated port which listened by proxy?

Tags: iptables

In android, i have a proxy daemon which listens on a dedicated port and would like to relay the visit of some specific domains,but not for others, for example: this proxy will relay the request for www.yahoo.com, but does not affect www.google.com.

Is it possible to use iptables to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Normally it can't do that. Iptables routes/blocks traffic from/to IP's/Ports. Maybe a plugin can do that, but I am not firm with iptables plugins, and I don't know anything about iptables on android.

Apache can forward connections to, maybe that's the right choice for you.

Comment: Thanks Biber for the kind help,  iptables on the android is similar as that in the pc/server world.  Apache seems too big to place on our phone. If so, is it possible to only redirect some specific domains' request to a dedicated port, then proxy will handle the rest work?

Comment: the reason to do this is that I would like to make the proxy care for the things it has to do.

Comment: I think, if I understand it, that's the wrong solution. If you use https you can't figure out (with iptables or a proxy) which domain (virtual domain) you want to connect to....
Maybe it is better the client which starts the connection select the proxy (or none proxy)

Comment: I just did a test to listen all network traffic with iptables, it seems working for https, but my problem is that i cannot limit the domain i want to listen as seems this line does not work at all: "iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT 1 -p tcp  -m owner --uid-owner root --dport 80 -d www.yahoo.com -j ACCEPT"

Comment: You do a "-d www.yahoo.com", so iptables takes the ip of www.yahoo.com. But there are many others domains which can have the same IP as www.yahoo.com (virtual domains), also www.yahoo.com can have more than one IP (load balancing....).

Comment: thanks biber, so seems the solution will not work? if it is, looks sad and i have to turn to other complex solution, any suggestion?